# prepared insert statements in for loop works only for first iteration..(PHP)

Tags: php

I want to insert number of records using following script. But, only the first one gets inserted. After that, it just stops without showing any error. What is wrong with these prepared statement execution?

```
//$dbc = database connection  //shortan here 
// $mid[] = {1,2,3,4};  //sortened here.

$q5 = "INSERT INTO user_book_trn(user_id, member_id, book_id, date_read, lang_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?,  now(), ?)";

$s5 = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q5);
//Bind the variables:
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($s5, 'iiii', $user_id, $member_id, $book_id, $lang_id);

foreach($mid as $mk => $mv) { //check for each selected check box value from member list:

    $q2 = "SELECT user_id, member_id, book_id FROM user_book_trn WHERE user_id = {$_SESSION['myuser']['userid']} and member_id = {$mv} and book_id= {$w}";

    $r3 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q2);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($r3) == 0) { //title is available for this user.

        //Assign the values to variables:
        $user_id = (int)$_SESSION['myuser']['userid'];
        $member_id = (int)$mv;
        $book_id = (int)$w;
        $lang_id = (int)$_SESSION['lid'];

        //just to check each iteration gets new values:
        echo "user_id : $user_id \n";
        echo "member_id : $member_id \n";
        echo "book_id : $book_id \n";

        //Execute the query:
        mysqli_stmt_execute($s5);
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) {
            //this runs ok just for the first iteration.. Why?

            echo "<p><b> The book $t is added. </b></p>";
            $_SESSION['bookid'] = $book_id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where and why this var_dump($mid)? I'm printing member_id for each iteration, just to make sure it is getting new value.

Comment: do it run `echo "user_id : $user_id ` the 2nd time? or it dies before that? you have 3 starting bracers `{`, but only one ending `}`, i hope thats becose the other 2 is outside the part you copy, if not add the 2 `}` and see if there any diference

Comment: yes it runs echo "user_id : $user_id" and other echo commands 2nd, third time also..just the statement is not executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know the exact details, but as far as I know the prepared statement is bound to a result set after execution. You need to reset it first

```
mysqli_stmt_reset($s);
```

http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.reset

Additional you should consider using *useful* variable names. And because you mentioned, that you cannot see any error:

```
mysqli_stmt_error_list($s5);
```

http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.error-list

http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.errno

http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.error

Comment: I added mysqli_stmt_reset($s5) after $_SESSION['bookid'] = $bookid; but, no success..

Comment: maybe `mysqli_affected_rows()` is `0`, or `-1` (error, see manual)? Have you tried the other functions/methods mentioned?